# How to ignore rescue_from in ApplicationController in rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, cancan, rspec-rails

By default, Cucumber ignores rescue_from in your ApplicationController and reports any exceptions directly.  This is accomplished by the following line in the Cucumber env.rb file

```
# in features/support/env.rb
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false
```

Is there a way to get rspec to ignore rescue_from as well?  (Specifically, I'm wishing that I could get rspec to ignore `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied`.)

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just put the same line into the spec_helper?

Why not just do the setup to have a logged in user present when testing?  Will be a better test.  You can put a hook into the spec_helper to do something before all your tests so you just put the sign in in one place for all your specs.